# Rsync exclude from root

Tags: rsync

I'm confused with rsync's exclude.

I'm trying to backup every starting with / but exclude /media/ /mnt/ /home/files/ and /home/backup

```
sudo rsync -a \
       --progress \
       --stats \
       --exclude-from=/home/files/ \
       --exclude-from=/media/ \
       --exclude-from=/mnt/ \
       --exclude-from=/home/backup/ \
   / /home/backup
```

Won't work.

I end up copying files to /home/backup/home/backup/...
I read that I have to write my excludes relative to my transfer root, but i guess if / is my transfer root then /media/ should be relative to that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
man rsync

--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```

exclude-from is used to point to a file that lists the folders that you don't want. Try the option --exclude

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect; that's why it isnt't working.

You say:

```
--exclude-from=/home/backup/
```

when you should simply say

```
--exclude="/home/backup/*"
```

Also, you are not using the

```
--delete-excluded
```

switch that can synchronize the directories.

As to your question at the end:  Yes, in your case you are specifying `/` as your beginning for the rsync.   So if you exclude `"tmp/*"` then it is indeed relative to `/` so it is the same as specifying `"/tmp/*"`